# como comparar se conjunto de dados de um array contém no outro array javascript

Tags: javascript

Como faço para comparar se conjunto de dados de um array contém no outro array javascript?

Array 1

```
//Combinações possíveis para acertar a carta
const equals = [
    ['imgCard_0', 'imgCard_6'],
    ['imgCard_1', 'imgCard_7'],
    ['imgCard_2', 'imgCard_8'],
    ['imgCard_3', 'imgCard_9'],
    ['imgCard_4', 'imgCard_10'],
    ['imgCard_5', 'imgCard_11'],
]
```

Array 2 de nome rotateCards criado dinamicamente conforme o usuário clica na carta

```
["imgCard_0", "imgCard_9"]
```

Preciso verificar  se as duas cartas clicadas por ele, estão nas possíveis combinações do array 1

tentei fazer com indexOf, mais sempre retorna -1, ou seja, não encontrado.

tentei também assim const equal = !rotateCards.some((val, idx) => val !== equals[idx]), e também sem sucesso até o momento

Também tentei desta forma sem sucesso

```
for (i = 0; i < equals.length; i++) {
        if (clickCard.indexOf(equals[i]) >= 0) {
            console.log(equals[i]);
        }
    }
```

Imagem que demonstra que mesmo a combinação estando correta ele retorna false.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentei desta forma, não sei o porquê ele sempre retorna false independente da comparação

Answer (score 2):

Se quer encontrar o índice de um elemento dentro de um array use o método [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) que retorna o índice do primeiro elemento na array que satisfaça a função de teste fornecida, caso contrário retorna `-1` indicando que nenhum elemento passou no teste.

```js
const equals = [
  ['imgCard_0', 'imgCard_6'],
  ['imgCard_1', 'imgCard_7'],
  ['imgCard_2', 'imgCard_8'],
  ['imgCard_3', 'imgCard_9'],
  ['imgCard_4', 'imgCard_10'],
  ['imgCard_5', 'imgCard_11'],
];

//Cartas selecionadas pelo usuário. 
//Como não foi informado se o sistema ordena dinamicamente os dados usei uma sequência válida porém em ordem invertida como exemplo.
let rotateCards = ["imgCard_10", "imgCard_4"];

//Localiza o índice de rotateCards em equals fazendo a comparação direta dos elementos correspondente 
//e também a comparação dos elementos em ordem invertida.
let idx = equals.findIndex((e) =>
     (e[0] == rotateCards[0] && e[1] == rotateCards[1]) 
  || (e[0] == rotateCards[1] && e[1] == rotateCards[0]) //Se a comparação em ordem invertida for desnecessária comente essa linha.
);

console.log(idx);
```

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente o javascript não consegue comparar arrays. Então `['oi'] == ['oi']` vai retornar `false`.

Pra fazer isso dar certo, você deve comparar eles como se fossem `strings`.

No seu caso, usar um [JSON stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) e um simples [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) já basta!

```js
// variável, só por didática
const selectedCard = ['imgCard_0', 'imgCard_6'];

const isEqual = equals.some(combination => {
    return JSON.stringify(combination) == JSON.stringify(selectedCard)
})

if (isEqual) { /* acertou a combinação! */ }
```

Answer (score -1):

Na função `checkCombination` é usado a função [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), assim conseguimos validar independe da ordem de escolha do seu deck e a quantidade de combinações.

```
const equals = [
    ['imgCard_0', 'imgCard_6'],
    ['imgCard_1', 'imgCard_7'],
    ['imgCard_2', 'imgCard_8'],
    ['imgCard_3', 'imgCard_9'],
    ['imgCard_4', 'imgCard_10'],
    ['imgCard_5', 'imgCard_11'],
    ['imgCard_5', 'imgCard_11', 'imgCard_7'],
]

function checkCombination(deck, combinations) {
    for(let a = 0; a < combinations.length; a++) {
        if(deck.length != combinations[a].length) continue
        const exists = deck.every((card) => combinations[a].indexOf(card) > -1)
        if(exists) return true
    }

    return false
}

checkCombination(['imgCard_5', 'imgCard_11', 'imgCard_7'], equals); //true
checkCombination(['imgCard_1', 'imgCard_5'], equals); //false
checkCombination(['imgCard_11', 'imgCard_5', 'imgCard_7'], equals); //true
checkCombination(['imgCard_0', 'imgCard_2', 'imgCard_7'], equals); //false
```